# How to update the docker kernel?

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and I have a doubt.

In all the tutorials I have seen the recommended docker kernel with version **>** *3.13* but I have version *3.10*

The question is: ¿How can I update the version of the docker kernel?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no thing like "Docker kernel". These articles refer to the Linux kernel. The version `3.10` is the default for CentOS/RHEL 7. If you use one of these distros, take into account that their "3.10" kernel has many features backported from future versions of vanilla kernels, so CentOS/RHEL 7 versions of kernel 3.10 are OK for Docker.

Comment: @DanilaKiver thank you very much, your comment has been very clear. You have solved all my doubts